# removeFromSuperviewがうまく機能しない

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
 var onVLine: onVerticalLine!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    onVLine = onVerticalLine(frame: CGRectZero)
    self.view.addSubview(onVLine)
    }

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if(onVLine != nil){
    self.onVLine.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    }

}



class onVerticalLine: UIView {
let _verticalLine: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    print("onlineinited")
    _verticalLine.removeAllPoints()
    self.userInteractionEnabled = false;
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor(white:1,alpha:0)
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width)
    self.center = CGPointMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 2, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height / 2)
    print("vertical",self.frame)
    _verticalLine.lineWidth = 1
    _verticalLine.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(frame.origin.x,0))
    _verticalLine.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y + frame.height))


}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)


}


override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    print("onLinedrawRected")
    UIColor.blueColor().setStroke()
    _verticalLine.stroke()

    }
}
```

上記のようなプログラムを組んでいます。
linesをViewControllerから消したいのですが、実行しても線が残ったままになってしまいます。

ちなみに、touchMovedにおいて

```
self.view.addSubview(onVLines)
self.onVLines.removeFromSuperView()
```

とするとうまく消えてくれます。

実行自体はされているようですがどうも画面に反映されません。
self.view.setNeedsDisplay()をしてみましたがそれも反応無しです。
どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 最低でも、当該箇所以外エラーの出ないコード、じっさいにXcodeのエディタで編集しているコードを基にしたコードの提示をお願いします。すくなくとも（最低のうちのさらに最低でも）、変数`trigger`がどう宣言され、どう値が代入されたかのコードの提示は必要です。

Comment: @Harawo どの程度コードを示すのがベストなのかわかっておらず、わかりにくい質問をして申し訳ありません。編集しましたが、もし、まだわかりづらい点があればご指定いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

removeFromSuperViewが機能していないと書かれていますが、機能はしていると思います。
touchesMovedはタッチ位置が変化したり、タッチの強さが変化するたびに呼び出されます。
UIViewを継承したonVerticalLineビューを生成しては追加を繰り返していますので、親viewにはあっという間に数十個のビューが追加された状態になります。だから、画面上に見えているのは同じ見た目の数十個のビューのうちの一番上のものが見えているのです。

一般的には、touchesBeganでビューを生成追加、touchesMoveで生成したビューの位置を変更、
touchesEndedとtouchesCancelledでビューを破棄、親viewから削除という流れになることが多いです。

touchesMoved内に、
print(__FUNCTION__)などを書いてデバッグすれば、気がついたのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
すみません、実はaddSubviewの事もよくわかっておらず、
     '  var onVLine: onVerticalLine!  '
の宣言は1つだけですが、addSubviewを行う度そのコピーがViewControllerに追加されるのでしょうか？
また、touchMovedにおいて、初期化後、addSubviewをする前に、
    ' if(onVLine != nil){
        onVLine.removefromSuperView
    } 
    '
を追加したのですが、これでも消えてくれそうにありません。
回数としてはデバッグ画面から確認するに書かれた回数より1つ多く、最後にonVLine.removefromSuperViewが行われています。

お手数おかけしますが、もしよろしければ以上のことについて起きているであろうことについて教えていただけると幸いです。どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 「' var onVLine: onVerticalLine! ' の宣言は1つだけですが、addSubviewを行う度そのコピーがViewControllerに追加されるのでしょうか？」とありますが、おそらくコピーではありません。
onVerticalLineはおそらくUIViewを継承したクラスだと思います(構造体ではない)ので、参照です。
onVerticalLineでインスタンスを生成し、onVLineに設定しています。  
    
onVLine = onVerticalLine(frame: CGRectZero)  
でインスタンスを生成し、それをself.viewにaddSubviewしたときは、この一つ目のインスタンスがself.viewに追加されます。

次に、
onVLine = onVerticalLine(frame: CGRectZero)
が実行されたときは新たな別のインスタンスが生成され、
onVLineは２つ目のインスタンスを指している状態になるわけです。
１つ目のインスタンスをself.viewから外したい場合は、
１つ目のインスタンスに対してremoveFromSuperviewを呼び出す必要があります。

構造体とクラスはそれぞれ、値型、参照型なので、メモリ管理方式が違います。ご存知なければ、swift入門書やWEBで勉強してみましょう。